# T2-Space and Accumulation Point

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis, separation-axioms

### Let $(X, \tau)$ be $T_2-Space$ and $A \subseteq X$ and $x \in \overline A$ (closure of $A$ = $\overline A$)

### Then prove that $x$ is an accumulation point of  $A$ iff $\forall V \in V(x) , V \cap A\setminus \{x\}$ is infinite ($V(x)$ is all neighborhoods of x)

For first part of theorem can we prove by contradiction? Let $\forall V \in V(x)$ $V \cap A\setminus \{x\}$ be finite. How can I pursue this proof?

For converse direction can we say

$x$ is an accumulation point iff $\forall V \in V(x) , V \cap A\setminus \{x\} \neq \emptyset $

Since $V \cap A\setminus \{x\}$ is an infinite set it can't be $\emptyset $ because $\emptyset $ is finite. Is it wrong?

If someone can help me I'll be really glad.

Comment: I just realized that you use different definition of accumulation point? If not, my below proof should work for your question.

Comment: @user284331 I used x is an element of closure(A\{x}) iff x is accumulation point of A. Guessing contradiction was said in lecture. I think this contradiction should be about inifiniteness. I’d say that I need an exact proof, I am really confused :) What do you think about the other direction? Am I wrong?

Comment: You can look at my answer, I have edited.

Comment: So if $V\cap A-\{x\}$ is infinite, of course it is nonempty, so in this case $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$. My following answer actually proves that, if $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$, $V\cap A-\{x\}$ is not only nonempty, but it contains infinitely many elements, and the proof goes by contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually $T_{1}$ suffices. For a $V\in V(x)$, pick an $x_{2}\in V\cap A$ and $x_{2}\ne x$. Now find another $V_{2}\in V(x)$ such that $x_{2}\notin V_{2}$. Pick a $x_{3}\in V_{2}\cap A$, $x_{3}\ne x$, proceed infinitely.

Or, following the idea of the OP proof, assume that $F:=V\cap A-\{x\}$ is finite, as finite sets are closed in $T_{1}$ space, then so is $F$, so $F^{c}$ is open which containing $x$, hence $(F^{c}\cap V)\cap A-\{x\}\ne\emptyset$, say, $z\in (F^{c}\cap V)\cap A$, $z\ne x$, in particular, $z\in V$ and $z\in F^{c}$, then $z\notin V\cap A-\{x\}$, as $z\ne x$ and $z\in A$, we have $z\notin V$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so muc it is very very beneficial for me. I have one more question. Can we say V intersection A - {x} can not be empty set since it is infinite? Otherwise is it a nonsense?

Comment: Yes of course you can say that, saying the word infinite implicitly means that there exists at least one.

Comment: If I would not write proofs for two sides of iff conjuction our lecturer never accept it, she is meticulous :D Thank you so much again...

Comment: Good luck for you then. Welcome.