# $x$ is a limit point of a set of real numbers iff every neighborhood contains infinitely many points of the set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have the following definition of a limit point of a set of real numbers:

> $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \iff  \forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \,\exists a \in A: 0 \lt |a-x_0| \lt \varepsilon$

With this definition I want to prove the equivalent definition:

> $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \iff  \forall \varepsilon \gt 0$ the set $A \cap (x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon)$ contains infinitely many points.

How would one go about showing and using the *infinitely many points* property? I found only proofs for more general spaces than $\mathbb{R}$ and only for one direction of the implication. Can somebody help me with the standard proof in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You may look at my answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556208/t2-space-and-accumulation-point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ as follows. Let $a\in A\cap(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$. Set $a_0=a$. Take $0<\epsilon_0<|x-a_0|$. Then we can find an element of $\Bbb{R}$ in $A\cap(x-\epsilon_0,x+\epsilon_0)$. Name it $a_1$. As $a_0\not\in(x-\epsilon_0,x+\epsilon_0)$, so $a_1\ne a_0$. In this manner, suppose $a_n$ is already chosen, then fix $0<\epsilon_n<|x-a_n|$ and find an element in $A\cap(x-\epsilon_n,x+\epsilon_n)$. Name that element $a_{n+1}$. We see that $a_{n+1}\ne a_n$.

Now obviously $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}\in(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\leftarrow$ is trivial.

For $\rightarrow$, let $\epsilon>0$, then exist $a_1\in A$ such that $0<d(a_1,x_0)<\epsilon$. Now, put $\epsilon'=d(a,x_o)$ and use the definition again, and exist $a_2\in A$ such that $0<d(a_2,x_0)<\epsilon'<\epsilon$. Now, note that $a_1\neq a_2$.

Inductively, construct a sucesion $a_j$ (with different terms) such that $d(a_j,x_0)<\epsilon$, ie, $A\cap (x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$ contains infinitely many points

Answer (score 2):

Proof by contradiction. If the intersection had only a finite number of points, you could find an $\epsilon \gt 0$, such that there would be no a as required by the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses! Here is my proof which is based mainly on Abishanka Saha's answer. Let me know if anything is missing.

---

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

"$\implies$": We construct the sequence $a_n$ with $a_n \in A \cap (x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon)$ as follows.

Let $\varepsilon \gt 0$. Because $x_0$ is a limit point of $A$, there exists a $x_0 \neq a \in A$ so that

$$|a-x_0| \lt \varepsilon \iff -\varepsilon \lt a-x_0 \lt \varepsilon \iff x_0-\varepsilon \lt a \lt x_0+\varepsilon \iff a \in (x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon)$$

Define $a_0 := a$. Choose $\varepsilon_0$ so that $0 \lt \varepsilon_0 \lt |a_0-x_0| \lt \varepsilon$. Because $x_0$ is a limit point of $A$, there exists again a $x_0 \neq a_1 \in A$ so that $|a_1-x_0| \lt \varepsilon_0 \iff \ldots \iff a_1 \in (x_0-\varepsilon_0, x_0+\varepsilon_0)$. In that manner define each element recursively. Choose $\varepsilon_n$ so that $0 \lt \varepsilon_n \lt |a_n-x_0| \lt \varepsilon_{n-1}$. Then there exists $x_0 \neq a_{n+1} \in A$ so that $|a_{n+1}-x_0| \lt \varepsilon_n \iff \ldots \iff a_{n+1} \in (x_0-\varepsilon_n, x_0+\varepsilon_n)$. Because $\forall n: a_n \notin (x_0-\varepsilon_n, x_0+\varepsilon_n)$ it follows that $a_n \neq a_{n+1}$. Aditionally also $\forall n: a_n \in (x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon)$, since $(x_0-\varepsilon_n, x_0+\varepsilon_n) \subset (x_0-\varepsilon_{n-1}, x_0+\varepsilon_{n-1}) \subset \ldots \subset (x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon)$ and $0 \lt \varepsilon_n \lt \ldots \lt \varepsilon_0 \lt \varepsilon$.

So we have defined a sequence $(a_n)_n$ with $a_n \in A$ and $a_n \in (x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon)$. Therefore $a_n \in A \cap (x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon)$ and since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary the statement follows.

(Alternatively this could have been proven by contraposition)

"$\impliedby$": Let $\varepsilon \gt 0$ and $a \in A \cap (x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon)$ be one of the infinitely many elements. Per definition of the set intersection we get: $a \in A$ and

$$a \in (x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon) \iff x_0-\varepsilon \lt a \lt x_0+\varepsilon \iff -\varepsilon \lt a-x_0 \lt \varepsilon \iff |a-x_0| \lt \varepsilon$$

Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary the statement follows.